# ETIMEDOUT or reading only 0s from GY6500 MPU6500 using MycroPython on an ESP32

Tags: esp32, i2c, micropython

I'm trying to read data of a GY6500 MPU6500 sensor that has an accelerometer and a gyroscope using MicroPython on a ESP32 dev board.

The code is

```
# main.py -- put your code here!
import utime
from time import sleep
from machine import Timer, Pin, SoftI2C
#from mpu9250 import MPU9250
from mpu6500 import MPU6500, SF_DEG_S, SF_M_S2

# MPU6500 module was adjusted from:
# https://github.com/tuupola/micropython-mpu9250

# set up I2C serial communication protcol
i2c = SoftI2C(scl=Pin(25), sda=Pin(27))

# create MPU6500 instance 
mpu6500 = MPU6500(i2c, accel_sf=SF_M_S2, gyro_sf=SF_DEG_S)
#mpu6500 = MPU9250(i2c)

# read sensor function
def read_sensor(stringa):
    print(stringa, mpu6500.acceleration, mpu6500.gyro)

# hardware timer setup
#timer = Timer(0)
#timer.init(period=500, mode=Timer.PERIODIC, callback=read_sensor)

#for loop to read data every sleep time period

for i in range(0, 1000):
    read_sensor(i * 10)
    sleep(10/1000)
```

Sometimes I get ETIMEDOUT and going in the mpu6500.py source code seems the I2C connection has a problem, in particular either `self.i2c.readfrom_mem_into(self.address, register, buf)` or `self.i2c.writeto_mem(self.address, register, buf)` seem not to work properly.

```
  File "/lib/mpu6500.py", line 101, in __init__
  File "/lib/mpu6500.py", line 189, in _accel_fs
  File "/lib/mpu6500.py", line 186, in _register_char
OSError: [Errno 116] ETIMEDOUT
MicroPython v1.20.0 on 2023-04-26; ESP32 module with ESP32
Type "help()" for more information.
```

while when it works I read only 0s even when moving the GY6500 on the breadboard.

```
>>> ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0030,len:4656
load:0x40078000,len:13284
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40080400,len:3712
entry 0x4008064c
0 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
10 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
20 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
30 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
40 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
[...]
```

So far I checked whether all the wires are correctly connected and I connected FSYNC to GND as told in the MPU6500's documentation. I tried to supply a voltage of 3.3V and of 5V I know it should not affect the software but who knows. Then, I even tried switching the SCL with the SDA (in the code) with ETIMEDOUT as a result but sometimes I manage to read random numbers. I edited the readings period to 5ms, 10ms, 100ms, 1000ms with scarce results. I edited the mpu6500.py from I2C to SoftI2C as the first one is deprecated.

Comment: Did you use pull-up resistors on SCL and SDA?

Comment: I put two 4.7KOhm pull-up resistors and the device seems working! Thank you @romkey

Comment: why use soft I2C? normal I2C works fine (tried it just now) and doesn't need pUps